# TP5100 battery charging - 1S

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am trying to use a TP5100 for 1S Li-po charging. In my application, the 5V input is always connected to a battery charger IC. My system consumes 2A continuously.

When my battery is fully charged, it should have a voltage output of 4.2V and virtually no current, and the 5V input stays connected.

How is the system current is supposed to be drawn through the TP5100? The charger IC would not give out any current in this case, right?

Comment: Please link the data sheet of the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then How System current is supposed to be drawn through TP5100 ?

It isn't.  That chip isn't designed for that; it's designed to just charge a battery.  You will need a chip that is designed to both charge the battery, manage current division into the load, and boost battery voltage to 5V when input current is insufficient.  They are out there.